# What is the difference between getHeight() and getNumRows() in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

#### Background:

According to the [documentation on Class `Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range), there are two separate methods for obtaining the number of rows in a given range:

> #### `getNumRows()`
>
> Returns the number of rows in this range.
>
> ```js
> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
> var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
>
> var range = sheet.getRange("B2:D5");
> Logger.log(range.getNumRows());
> ```
>
> **Return**
>
> **`Integer`** — The number of rows in this range.

and

> #### `getHeight()`
>
> Returns the height of the range.
>
> ```js
> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
> var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
>
> var range = sheet.getRange("B2:D4");
> // logs 3.0
> Logger.log(range.getHeight());
> ```
>
> **Return**
>
> **`Integer`** — The height of the range.

#### Test:

Now, testing the following code snippet:

```js
function diffTest() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 
  var dr = ss.getDataRange();
  var h = dr.getHeight();
  var nr = dr.getNumRows();
  
  console.log(h);
  console.log(nr);
}
```

Will output the same for both methods - whether this is arange obtained programmatically, or a named range:

```
Dec 9, 2020, 11:18:08 AM    Debug   26
Dec 9, 2020, 11:18:08 AM    Debug   26
```

**Things I have ruled out:**

- The literal height of the cells do not affect this, if changed manually in the UI
- The number of newlines in a cell do not change this height either

#### Question:

*What is the difference, if any, between the methods `Range.getHeight()` and `Range.getNumRows()`?*

Comment: I don't think there's any.

Comment: I thought the same, but once upon a time I thought the same about `getActiveCell()` and `getCurrentCell()` so thought I'd put the question out there all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*There is no difference. They both return the number of rows in a given range.*